# Transpose JSON Nesting Convert to CSV

Tags: json, api, csv, terminal, transpose

When I use ProPublica's API, I can get a list of Members of the 115th Congress simply via Terminal using:

```
curl "https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/115/senate/members.json" -H "X-API-Key: "MY_API_KEY"
```

I get a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
   "status":"OK",
   "copyright":" Copyright (c) 2017 Pro Publica Inc. All Rights Reserved.",
   "results":[
  {
     "congress": "115",
     "chamber": "Senate",


     "num_results": 101,
     "offset": 0,
     "members": [
          {
             "id": "A000360",
             "api_uri":"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/A000360.json",
             "first_name": "Lamar",
             "middle_name": null,
             "last_name": "Alexander",
             "date_of_birth": "1940-07-03",
             "party": "R",
             "leadership_role": null,
             "twitter_account": "SenAlexander",
             "facebook_account": "senatorlamaralexander",
             "youtube_account": "lamaralexander",
             "govtrack_id": "300002",
             "cspan_id": "5",
             "votesmart_id": "15691",
             "icpsr_id": "40304",
             "crp_id": "N00009888",
             "google_entity_id": "/m/01rbs3",
             "url": "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public",
             "rss_url": "https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/?a=RSS.Feed",
             "contact_form": "http://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=Email",
             "domain": null,
             "in_office": true,
             "dw_nominate": 0.323,
             "ideal_point": null,
             "seniority": "15",
             "next_election": "2020",
             "total_votes": 187,
             "missed_votes": 7,
             "total_present": 0,
             "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:tn",
             "office": "455 Dirksen Senate Office Building",
             "phone": "202-224-4944",
             "fax": "202-228-3398",
             "state": "TN",
             "senate_class": "2",
             "state_rank": "senior",
             "lis_id": "S289"
             ,"missed_votes_pct": 3.74,
             "votes_with_party_pct": 98.89
           },
                       {
             "id": "B000575",
             "api_uri":"https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/B000575.json",
             "first_name": "Roy",
             "middle_name": null,
             "last_name": "Blunt",
             "date_of_birth": "1950-01-10",
             "party": "R",
             "leadership_role": null,
             "twitter_account": "RoyBlunt",
             "facebook_account": "SenatorBlunt",
             "youtube_account": "SenatorBlunt",
             "govtrack_id": "400034",
             "cspan_id": "45465",
             "votesmart_id": "418",
             "icpsr_id": "29735",
             "crp_id": "N00005195",
             "google_entity_id": "/m/034fn4",
             "url": "https://www.blunt.senate.gov/public",
             "rss_url": "http://www.blunt.senate.gov/public/?a=RSS.Feed",
             "contact_form": "https://www.blunt.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/contact-roy",
             "domain": null,
             "in_office": true,
             "dw_nominate": 0.431,
             "ideal_point": null,
             "seniority": "7",
             "next_election": "2022",
             "total_votes": 187,
             "missed_votes": 2,
             "total_present": 0,
             "ocd_id": "ocd-division/country:us/state:mo",
             "office": "260 Russell Senate Office Building",
             "phone": "202-224-5721",
             "fax": "202-224-8149",
             "state": "MO",
             "senate_class": "3",
             "state_rank": "junior",
             "lis_id": "S342"
             ,"missed_votes_pct": 1.07,
             "votes_with_party_pct": 99.46
           },
```

Etc.

But when I convert it to CSV, it's only two rows (one of which being column headers) that stretch for almost 4,000 columns. Seems like the way the JSON is nested, this is the only way I can convert it to a CSV. Want it converted to CSV so I can import properly into SQL.

I counted the headers and there are 39 per member of congress. They're formulated as members/0/id, members/0/api_url, etc. up to members/100/id, members/100/api_url, etc.

Is there anyway I can do this without manual alteration? In an ideal world I'd be able to run my terminal script, output into CSV, and then upload into SQL to work with it. Would've worked fine if it ended up being 100 rows with 39 columns, instead of one row and 3,900 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

If the file `filter.jq` contains

```
  .results[].members
| ( .[0] | keys ),
  ( .[] as $x | [ $x[] ] )
| @csv
```

and your data is in a file called `data.json` then

```
jq -M -r -f filter.jq data.json
```

will generate

```
"api_uri","contact_form","crp_id","cspan_id","date_of_birth","domain","dw_nominate","facebook_account","fax","first_name","google_entity_id","govtrack_id","icpsr_id","id","ideal_point","in_office","last_name","leadership_role","lis_id","middle_name","missed_votes","missed_votes_pct","next_election","ocd_id","office","party","phone","rss_url","senate_class","seniority","state","state_rank","total_present","total_votes","twitter_account","url","votes_with_party_pct","votesmart_id","youtube_account"
"A000360","https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/A000360.json","Lamar",,"Alexander","1940-07-03","R",,"SenAlexander","senatorlamaralexander","lamaralexander","300002","5","15691","40304","N00009888","/m/01rbs3","https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public","https://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/?a=RSS.Feed","http://www.alexander.senate.gov/public/index.cfm?p=Email",,true,0.323,,"15","2020",187,7,0,"ocd-division/country:us/state:tn","455 Dirksen Senate Office Building","202-224-4944","202-228-3398","TN","2","senior","S289",3.74,98.89
"B000575","https://api.propublica.org/congress/v1/members/B000575.json","Roy",,"Blunt","1950-01-10","R",,"RoyBlunt","SenatorBlunt","SenatorBlunt","400034","45465","418","29735","N00005195","/m/034fn4","https://www.blunt.senate.gov/public","http://www.blunt.senate.gov/public/?a=RSS.Feed","https://www.blunt.senate.gov/public/index.cfm/contact-roy",,true,0.431,,"7","2022",187,2,0,"ocd-division/country:us/state:mo","260 Russell Senate Office Building","202-224-5721","202-224-8149","MO","3","junior","S342",1.07,99.46
```